# Change CSS display on windows resize and toggle

Tags: jquery

When I use the toggle function and I resize the window the nav still displays none, and this resize function doesn't work. Any advice?

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $("#menu").click(function() { $( ".nav" ).fadeToggle("slow", "linear");});

$(window).resize(function() { if ($(window).width() < 768) { $('.nav').css("display", "none");} else {$('.nav').css("display", "inline-block");}});});
```

I also want the nav bar to disappear when the click is not on the menu area. It currently disappears only when I click on the svg icon. I tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).click(function(event) {if(!$(event.target).is('#menu')) {$(".nav").hide();}});
```

Here the live page https://sebalaini.github.io/NewPortfolio/
and here the repo https://github.com/sebalaini/NewPortfolio

Comment: You are missing the period (`.`) in your selector on the second line. Check that you meant `.nav` instead of `nav`.

Comment: i see :) a stupid error, some advise about hidden the nav when i click on the body instead of the menu icon ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you missed a period:

Try

```
$('.nav').css("display", "inline-block");
```

Instead of

```
$('nav').css("display", "inline-block");
```

jQuery is looking for a nav tag instead of a .nav class.

Comment: i see :) a stupid error, some advise about hidden the nav when i click on the body instead of the menu icon ?

Comment: Why don't you try jQuery's .not() here?  Something like  $('.wrapper').not('.nav').click(function(){$('.nav').hide();}); maybe.